# Does Echo Form stack with itself?

Tags: slay-the-spire

The description for the Power card Echo Form states

> The first card you play each turn is played twice

What happens if you play Echo Form multiple times in a battle? Does the first card played in a turn get played even more times?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Playing Echo Form multiple times in a battle will cause the first X cards played each turn to be played twice, where X is the number of times that echo form was played (The buff will show the number X). If you've played 2 Echo forms, you can play a Strike, which gets played twice, and then a Defend, which also gets played twice. Following cards will then be played once.